# Is it possible to obtain a stable floating point floor in numpy?

Tags: numpy, floating-point, ieee-754

In the following code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([0., 0., .1])
b = np.asarray([0., 0., 1.1])
c = np.asarray([0., 0., 4.1])

b -= np.floor(b) # same results with np.rint(b) or b.astype(int)
c -= np.floor(c) # same results with np.rint(c) or c.astype(int)

np.floor(a*10) # => [0., 0., 1.0]
np.floor(b*10) # => [0., 0., 1.0]
np.floor(c*10) # => [0., 0., 0.] # <= !!!
```

I understand the usual disclaimers about floating point being inexact, and how in this case, I'm probably hitting an edge case where `4.1 - 4 = 0.9999999` or some such.

My question is: is there a way to work around this instability in a sane way?

**Edit with answer**:

using the `decimals` keyword in `np.round` yields the expected (least astonishing) stability, namely:

```
import numpy as np

c = np.asarray([0., 0., 4.1])

c -= np.floor(c)

np.floor(c*10) # => [0., 0., 0.]
np.round(c*10, decimal=0) # => [0., 0., 1.]
```

Comment: "is there a way to work around this" --> Note that code constants, like 4.1, are not _exactly_ encodable into a FP value.  The nearest is 4.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375.  Further, `c*10` incurs a rounding. The usual solution is to move to integer math instead of FP.  Alternatively change your expectations.

Comment: If you know you're working only until a certain number of decimal points, you can call `np.round(array, decimals = 3)` or whatever it is you need. I generally make `decimals` maybe 1 or 2 larger than what you'll actually need.

Comment: Ahh fantastic. I had forgotten about the `decimals` keyword. This will give me exactly the kind of stability that's missing here.